# Automatically Calculating total cost based on the number of selected items using jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel-8

I have the following code that is aimed at calculating the total cost based on the number of rooms of each type selected by a user.

My problem is that the script is only incrementing the cost even if `roomNo` is changed from a higher number to a lower one. I.e. if the user had selected `2` and then changes it to `1`, the `numberOfRooms` becomes `3` instead of `1` making the cost increase the same way instead of reducing.

Is there a way through which I could know if a particular select value has been reduced? Here is the option select structure from which the `roomNo` comes

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".quantity").on('change', function() {
    var roomNo = $(this).children('option:selected').val();
    var cost = $(this).parent().parent().find('.charge p').text();
    var totalRoomCost = roomNo * cost;
    var oldRoomNo = $('.room_no').val();
    var numberOfRooms = parseInt(oldRoomNo) + parseInt(roomNo);
    var oldCost = $('.total_cost').val();
    var final_cost = parseInt(oldCost) + totalRoomCost;
    //alert(totalCost);
    $('.room_no').val(numberOfRooms);
    $('.total_cost').val(final_cost);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><u class="text-success"><b>Delux Single</b></u><br><small></small></td>
    <td> <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
    <td colspan="3">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="charge">
              <p>1600</p>
            </td>
            <td class="text-success">Bed Only</td>
            <td>
              <select name="quantity" class="quantity" required="">
                <option value="">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="charge">
              <p>1800</p>
            </td>
            <td class="text-success">Bed and breakfast</td>
            <td>
              <select name="quantity" class="quantity" required="">
                <option value="">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="charge">
              <p>2000</p>
            </td>
            <td class="text-success">Half Board</td>
            <td>
              <select name="quantity" class="quantity" required="">
                <option value="">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="charge">
              <p>2200</p>
            </td>
            <td class="text-success">Full Board</td>
            <td>
              <select name="quantity" class="quantity" required="">
                <option value="">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td><a href="">Reserve</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
 <div class="col-2">
       <div class='form-group'>
            <input type='text' name ='quantity' class='form-control room_no' readonly='readonly' value="0"/>
              </div>
              <div class='form-group'>
                    <input type='text' name ='total_cost' class='form-control total_cost' readonly='readonly' value="0"/>
               </div>
               <input type='submit' value='Reserve'/>
                </div>
```

Comment: where is `room_no` and `total_cost` ?

Comment: @Swati they are class names of input fieelds in the program I have dited  to include them

Comment: You'll need to use an if statement to check if the values of the select field has changed upward or downward. meaning you will need  to figure out how to store the initial value so as to know which one has changed and by how much then perform the appropriate operation either incremental or decremental

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.each` loop to iterate through your select-box and get value of charges and room calculate them and finally add result inside required inputs .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".quantity").on('change', function() {
    var totalRoomCost = 0
    var numberOfRooms = 0
    //loop through each select
    $(".quantity").each(function() {
      var roomNo = $(this).val() != "" ? parseInt($(this).val()) : 0;
      var cost = parseInt($(this).closest("tr").find('.charge p').text());
      totalRoomCost += roomNo * cost;
      numberOfRooms += roomNo
    })

    $('.room_no').val(numberOfRooms);
    $('.total_cost').val(totalRoomCost);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><u class="text-success"><b>Delux Single</b></u><br><small></small></td>
    <td> <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
    <td colspan="3">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="charge">
              <p>1600</p>
            </td>
            <td class="text-success">Bed Only</td>
            <td>
              <select name="quantity" class="quantity" required="">
                <option value="">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="charge">
              <p>1800</p>
            </td>
            <td class="text-success">Bed and breakfast</td>
            <td>
              <select name="quantity" class="quantity" required="">
                <option value="">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="charge">
              <p>2000</p>
            </td>
            <td class="text-success">Half Board</td>
            <td>
              <select name="quantity" class="quantity" required="">
                <option value="">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="charge">
              <p>2200</p>
            </td>
            <td class="text-success">Full Board</td>
            <td>
              <select name="quantity" class="quantity" required="">
                <option value="">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td><a href="">Reserve</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="col-2">
  <div class='form-group'>
    <input type='text' name='quantity' class='form-control room_no' readonly='readonly' value="0" />
  </div>
  <div class='form-group'>
    <input type='text' name='total_cost' class='form-control total_cost' readonly='readonly' value="0" />
  </div>
  <input type='submit' value='Reserve' />
</div>
```

Comment: Will I need to use the loop together with an if statement to check if the change is an increment or a decrement?

Comment: No need to do that . Did you run above snippet ? Try inc/dec values ..See what it gives you .

Comment: yes I have and it works as expected, just wanted to understand it further

Comment: Above code loop through all selects and get values from them so no matter whether you inc or dec it will calculate total  .